# Capturo una imagen de desde la cámara y al subirla a firestorage/firebase esta llega en blanco o nula

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy tratando de subir una imagen al storage de firebase, pero la imagen llega siempre nula y es porque al tomar la foto y capturar la url del storage del telefono para luego enviarla, la foto esta nula o en blanco, creo que se debe a la ruta que se le asigna, pero estoy usando la recomendada por la documentación.

el file_path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.project.guanafire/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

codigo que le da nombre a la foto almacenada en el storage local

```
 String currentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        Log.d("Pantalla2", "Mau2");
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "Backup_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        //File image = new File(storageDir,imageFileName+".jpg");

        File image = File.createTempFile(
               imageFileName,  /* prefix */
               ".png",         /* suffix */
               storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d("Pantalla2 image path", image.getPath());

        Log.d("Pantalla2 current", currentPhotoPath);

        return image;
    }
```

el codigo que abre la camara

```
 static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    public void abrirCamara(View view) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.project.guanafire.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                uriImg = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.project.guanafire.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI.toString());
                uriImg = photoURI;
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
```

el onActivityResult que captura la imagen en un ImageView, lo raro es que la imagen si se plasma bien en el ImageView, pero cuando se sube a firebase llega en blanco y si busco en la carpeta dentro del celular donde genera la imagen igual ella esta en blanco

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imgCamara.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Que se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: Hago un log para ver que ruta le generó y me muestra lo siguiente
image path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.project.guanafire/files/Pictures/Backup_20200604_175247_9148425961855745273.png

Luego un Log a la variable uriImg y enseña esto: 
content://com.project.guanafire.fileprovider/my_images/Backup_20200604_175247_9148425961855745273.png

Comment: Por último recibo esta excepción:  W/Bundle: Key output expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable